# Cloning private repo at gitlab works without password?

Tags: git, gitlab

I just made a private git repository at [gitlab](https://gitlab.com) and I don't have SSH setup. (I can't use it because visual studio doesn't support it)
[image]
I tried to clone it using the Git Bash and it didn't prompt me to enter a password (It should if it is private).
[image]
So how can I protect my repo from being cloned by random people just by knowing the link? Why is it not prompting for a password?

Comment: Can you push to the project you cloned?  It should prompt you for your password information.  Also, I notice you're using HTTPS to clone the repository, but saying you don't have SSH setup.  They're different protocols so the fact you don't have SSH doesn't matter.

Comment: @AndrewWylie, yes I can push to it. I don't really understand. If it is private, why can I pull and push to it without password?

Comment: You shouldn't be able to.  I just tested myself and wasn't able to.  The only thing I can think of is that your credentials are saved somewhere.  It sounds like you're on Windows, maybe check the [credential store](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/manage-stored-passwords-certificates-and-other-credentials)?

Comment: I checked the credential store and saw my password saved there. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Sure, no problem :).  Try to put more information in the question next time.  Initially I thought you were on Mac OS so I wasted some time poking around.  I've submitted an actual answer so maybe you can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the sounds of it you've most likely previously saved your credentials on the OS.  It sounds like you're on Windows, so maybe check the [credential store](https://web.archive.org/web/20150306043144/http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/manage-stored-passwords-certificates-and-other-credentials)?

Comment: If you cannot find credentials store, reference http://security.stackexchange.com/a/15575/49381